# How can I Trigger local maven project from remote Jenkins?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have created a simple Selenium+java maven project locally on my machine. I am able to execute the testing locally triggering it with Maven.

I want to trigger it from  Jenkins (which is installed on a remote machine (my company's QA server))

I am using the option 'custom workspace' of Jenkins.

As the Jenkins is on the server, it's not able to understand/locate the local path

```
'C:\Automation\MavenProject\'
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with master-slave concepts in Jenkins. Slave machine would be your windows machine which will connect to master Jenkins with the help of some jars. You need to create a node on your Jenkins server and after adding the configuration, you need to download the corresponding slave jars on your machine. Once you execute those jars on your local machine, it will interact with Jenkins server. Your Jenkins job can then perform further activities on your slave machine.

[image]

Also in the Jenkins job, you need to refer to this node by enabling the following option.

*Restrict where this project can be run*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1)Create a Maven Project in Jenkins, you may have to install some plugin if its not visible

2. Pushing your code to some type of version Control like Github
3. You need to configure Jenkins to provide GitHub build information and POM Location
4. Since you Jenkins is hosted up in the server, you have be able to access it public, you need to download Github integration plugin and configure jenkins to provide GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling and similar action in github itself

This should get you going, also google or youtube, lots of solution , one example
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PhxZamqYJws